# Reading website data automatically with POST requests using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to automatically read data from a website where first I need to fill in some fields, submit the form and then read the data that appears. I am new to this but I wrote a code which obviously doesn't work and the result is HTTP Error 500. What am I missing here? or How do I fix this?

Also, I am happy to do this using BS4 as well because I will need to build upon this code.

**Website**: http://www.mlindex.ml.com/GISPublic/bin/SnapShot.asp

**Inputs required**: Index Ticker = H0A0 , Base Curr = LOC , Date = 09/22/2017

I checked the source code and went through the js form that submits the POST request and created the code and payload accordingly:

```
import requests

post_data = {'hdnDate':'1/1/2016', 'hdnAction':'SS', 'hdnSelCurr':'0,LOC', 'hdnCurrDesc':'USD', 'hdnSelTitle':'Hedged', 'txtSSCUSIP':'H0A0'}

# POST some form-encoded data:
post_response = requests.post(url='http://www.mlindex.ml.com/GISPublic/bin/Snapshot.asp', data=post_data)
print post_response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `'cboSnapCurr': 0, 'cboSSHedge' : 1` from the payload data, as the server that handles the request is expecting those values.

> post_data = {'hdnDate':'1/1/2016', 'hdnAction':'SS', 'hdnSelCurr':'0,LOC', 'hdnCurrDesc':'USD', 'hdnSelTitle':'Hedged', 'txtSSCUSIP':'H0A0', 'cboSnapCurr': 0, 'cboSSHedge' : 1}

Comment: thanks, this gave HTTP response 200 which I believe means "OK". How do I get the actual HTML response so that I can read the output text from the from?

Comment: @dsauce `post_response.text`

Comment: thanks again! I'll be able to mark the answer as accepted in a couple of minutes. Meanwhile, could you please tell how I can just get the parsed text and not the entire html?

Comment: Convert the text into BeautifulSoup and parse each table row to get the data that you want. Use [this](https://srome.github.io/Parsing-HTML-Tables-in-Python-with-BeautifulSoup-and-pandas/) as a reference.